# Set content_for for all pages on the site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a `yield` in my `application.html.erb`,

```
<%= yield(:alert_area) %>
```

... and I want to set content for this area for every page on the site (that uses the layout). The content cannot be hardcoded in the view because it must only display in certain situations (i.e. "*Your profile is incomplete, click here to complete it!*")

How can I do this? I can know I can try using `content_for` in the `ApplicationController` but that seems like it is breaking the MVC pattern by putting content in the controller. Plus, I was hitting a dead end doing it that way anyway.

What is the proper Rails MVC way to stick dynamic content on every page of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as what bukk530 suggests, instead of a `yield`/`content_for` construct use a `render`/`partial` construct, and in the partial just have a conditional so it only renders something when you want it to.  Eg.

```
- flash.each do |name, message|
  %div{ class: "flash flash-#{name}" }= message
```

Comment: Geez. How did I not see this before? I guess I just need a break!

Comment: Yeah, honestly I don't know why the standard Rails layout template doesn't just include something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using `flash`, it is stored in the session and it shows only one time after it has been set.

Example:

application.html.erb:

```
<span class="error"><%= flash[:error] %></span>
```

controller:

```
def raise_error
    flash[:error] = "Hi! i'm an error!" # Use i18n here
    redirect_to :somewhere
end
```